# 'Unspecified error' on preventing page postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, telerik, keypress

I have a RadTextBox on a page within a RadPageView, defined as:

```
<telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtReport" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="500"
    ClientEvents-OnKeyPress="Report_KeyPress">
</telerik:RadTextBox>
```

On key press, it tracks that it changed in JavaScript like:

```
function Report_KeyPress(sender, e) {
    if (_changed == false) {
        _changed = true;
    }
}
```

On before unload, I tried to return the message as:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    if (!!_changed == true) {
        var e = e || window.event;
        var msg = 'Changes have been made.  Are you sure you want to discard these changes?';

        if (e) {
            e.returnValue = msg;
        }
        else {
            return msg;
        }
    }
}
```

Which in IE 9 on Windows 7 shows the confirm prompt with the message, and buttons to leave the page or stay on the page.  When I click leave page, it works great; when I click stay on page, it blows up on the following line:

```
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
  theForm.submit(); //Error line
}
```

With the error:

> Unhandled exception at line 33, column 9 in page.aspx
>
> 0x80004005 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unspecified error.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

Although it's an old link, this helped me:
http://tinisles.blogspot.ro/2005/10/onbeforeunload-throwing-errors-in-ie.html

The issue is not explained though, it seems it is a known IE issue.